# Where to go with continuity?

Tags: analysis, continuity

I've started to see continuity at university. The lecturer has given the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of continuity, but we've seen applications of those only to silly examples of functions: Polynomial functions, quadratic functions, etc. In most of these functions, it is visually clear that they are continuous.

But reading [here](http://www.mathcs.org/analysis/reals/cont/contin.html), they say that there are some examples of functions that are a lot more complicated to deal intuitively. That's what I'm curious about: Where to go with continuity? Most of the things I've seen until now are silly and could be made visually, what would be impossible to do visually? Why is it important?

I'd like to know a little more about the motivation (and perhaps history) of continuity to know a little better where I'm stepping on and where does it lead one to.

Comment: You might find the [Thomae function](http://www.google.com/search?q=Thomae+function) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a broad question:

- First off, there is a more general notion of continuity from topology. If you are unfamiliar with topologies then simply read the definition on wikipedia, they do a decent job of motivating it. A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is said to be continuous if for every open set $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Using this definition, we have completely avoided talking about continuity in terms of a metric (a notion of distance) like the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition uses.
- We can construct very complicated functions which have strange sets of discontinuities. See [Thomae's Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)